# Hunchentoot/cl-who page composition

Tags: common-lisp, hunchentoot

Hunchentoot/cl-who Page Composition

I'm trying to put together a few pages in hunchentoot as an experiment, and I'm running into an unexpected wall. As an example, I have the following template macro.

```
(defmacro page-template ((&key title) &body body)
  `(with-html-output-to-string 
    (*standard-output* nil :prologue t :indent t)
    (:html :xmlns "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" :xml\:lang "en" :lang "en"
           (:head (:meta :http-equiv "Content-Type" :content "text/html;charset=utf-8")
                  (:title ,(format nil "~@[~A - ~]Test Site" title)))
           (:body ,@body))))
```

Now when I have a pure text page, or one filled with html literals like

```
(define-easy-handler (test-page :uri "/") ()
  (page-template (:title "Splash Page") (:p "Testing testing")))
```

everything is a-ok. The page outputs properly and I can see te efforts of my code instantly. However, when I have a page which is made up of redundant elements, it's not as simple. For example, lets say I have a page on which for whatever reason I want to display three RSS newsfeeds. This is a sufficiently complex component that I want to abstract it out, so to my minnd, I should be able to do something like

```
(define-easy-handler (test-feed :uri "/feeds") ()
  (page-template (:title "Splash Page") 
                 (publish-newsfeed "http://nf-one.html")
                 (publish-newsfeed "http://nf-two.html")
                 (publish-newsfeed "http://nf-three.html")))


(defmacro publish-newsfeed (url &optional (item-limit 5))
  (flet ((get-text (s-tree node-path) (car (last (xmls-tools:find-subtree s-tree node-path)))))
    (let ((rss-feed (xmls:parse (drakma:http-request url))))
      `(:div :class "rss-feed"
              (:a :href ,(get-text rss-feed '("channel" "link")) :target "_top" (:h1 ,(get-text rss-feed '("channel" "title"))))
              (:ul ,@(mapcar #'(lambda (item)
                                 `(:li (:a :href ,(get-text item '("link")) :target "_top" (:h2 ,(get-text item '("title"))))
                                       (:p :class "date" ,(get-text item '("pubDate")))
                                       (:p ,(get-text item '("description")))))
                             (let ((items (xmls-tools:find-all-children (xmls-tools:find-subtree rss-feed '("channel")) "item")))
                               (if (> (length items) item-limit) (subseq items 0 item-limit) items))))))))
```

But the result of the above is a "Server Error" page. I'm not quire sure why; `page-template` is a macro so the calls to `publish-newsfeed` shouldn't be expanded until they're in the context of `with-html-output-to-string`. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Also, on closer inspection of the various Hunchentoot/cl-who tutorials, none of them seems to do this kind of page composition. Can anyone with some Hunchentoot experience tell me what the correct/canonical way of decomposing a page into components is?

---

EDIT:

Correct response by Ramarren below; the `with-html-output` macros work under different evaluation rules. The version of publish-newsfeed that would actually work in this situation is actually

```
(defun publish-newsfeed (url &optional (item-limit 5))
  (flet ((get-text (s-tree node-path) (car (last (xmls-tools:find-subtree s-tree node-path)))))
    (let* ((rss-feed (xmls:parse (drakma:http-request url)))
           (items (xmls-tools:find-all-children (xmls-tools:find-subtree rss-feed '("channel")) "item"))
           (ltd-items (if (> (length items) item-limit) (subseq items 0 item-limit) items)))
      (with-html-output 
       (*standard-output* nil :indent t)
       (:div :class "rss-feed"
             (:a :href (get-text rss-feed '("channel" "link")) :target "_top" (:h1 (str (get-text rss-feed '("channel" "title")))))
             (:ul (dolist (item ltd-items)
                    (htm (:li (:h2 (:a :href (get-text item '("link")) :target "_top" (str (get-text item '("title")))))
                              (:p :class "date" (str (get-text item '("pubDate"))))
                              (:p (str (get-text item '("description")))))))))))))
```

Note the removal of `mapcar` for `dolist` (I'm a Schemer, don't give me too much of a hard time about liking lambdas, but they weren't the right choice here), and the use of `htm` to escape blocks of html s-exps (h-exps?) that wouldn't otherwise be in context for `with-html-output`. Finally, I had to wrap text but NOT `:href` properties in `(str )` to get them to expand dynamically.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The macro `with-html-output-to-string` expands its body using [special evaluation rules](http://weitz.de/cl-who/#syntax). In particular, any not recognized forms are left as is, which means macros are not expanded before the html generating code is generated, which means by the time your `publish-newsfeed` macro is expanded by the standard compiler it is no longer in context of`with-html-output-to-string`. This is clear when expanding the macro [manually](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_mexp_.htm), especially using slime macroexpansion feature.

To make it work you should make `publish-newsfeed` a function and use `with-html-output` inside it with the same stream (either assume `*standard-output* everywhere or pass the stream explicitly).